# jQuery timer stops if user is not using browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I am trying to build a jQuery timer, but it stops when the browser is not focused or minimized. One of my thoughts is the code can use Ajax to pull data constantly from the server and update the timer, but my concern is that it may increase the pressure of the server. I wonder is there any way to check if user is using browser at frontend, so the code only needs to send Ajax request once the user returns.

My jQuery timer code snippet.

```
(function timer (offset) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var timestamp = {{ time }};
        timestamp = 5 * 60 - timestamp - offset;
        var minutes =  Math.floor(timestamp / 60);
        var seconds =  Math.floor(timestamp % 60);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + " : " + seconds;
        timer(offset + 0.5);
    }, 500);
})(0);
```

Comment: You can check [jquery.idle](https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle)

Comment: Are you trying to build a timer that just shows time elapsed?

Comment: @AuxTaco yes, show how much time left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.setTimeout`'s `delay` parameter is the *minimum* amount of time before the callback runs, [not a guaranteed time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). Instead of keeping a running total of time elapsed in the timeout, store the time the timer started and compare it to the current time. [`Performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) will give you an accurate timestamp measured in milliseconds.